# How to add new item to an object in Typescript dynamically?

Tags: typescript

```
var nodeRefMap = {};
function addNodeRef(key: String, item: Object){
       console.log("Before:");
       console.log(nodeRefMap);
       nodeRefMap = Object.assign({key: item}, nodeRefMap);
       console.log("After:");
       console.log(nodeRefMap);
}
addNodeRef("123",{});
addNodeRef("345",{});
```

I would like to add some new parameter with the above function in Typescript, but I have a problem of setting up the key of the object.
The expected return should be:

```
{
   "123": {},
   "345": {},
}
```

However, the actual result is:

```
{
   "key": {},
}
```

What changes I need to make to achieve this?

Comment: This isn't a typescript specific problem. In Object.assign, you need to use `{[key]: item}`. The square brackets instruct js to use the value of key instead of the word key. Since this is a typescript question, the type of nodeRefMap should be `Record<string, object>`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is you pass not the type of string there, you should change your function's input arguments from this: `(key: String, item: Object)` to this `(key: string, item: object)`. This way you declare the **type** of your input argument. Also `nodeRefMap = Object.assign({}, {[key]: item});` you should assign this way.

The following code works fine.

```
let nodeRefMap:{[key: string]: object};
function addNodeRef(key: string, item: object){
       console.log("Before:");
       console.log(nodeRefMap);
       nodeRefMap = Object.assign({}, {[key]: item});
       console.log("After:");
       console.log(nodeRefMap);
}
addNodeRef("123",{"a":1});
addNodeRef("345",{"b":2});
```